# Plugin Facebook like doesn't appear in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

For some time now, I realized that the Facebook plugin for likes is no longer showing on the page, as if I didn't have such a thing. This only happens in Firefox. The strange thing is that in other major browsers, all of them updated, the information is correctly shown.

Has anything been changed? Does it work for you?

Thank you very much.

PS I have also tested it in a blank page (thinking it might be a css problem). Even in this case, without css, it still doesn't work in Firefox.

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s);
   js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ro_RO/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }  (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
...
...
<div id="facebook"> 
 <div class="fb-like" data-href=https://my_page data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
</div>
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any console error when running the code on Firefox?

Comment: Yes I did. Thank you for the tip. I solved the problem and now it's working. I did not know about the console error. I would have looked sooner.